# Flag declined after edit has been made

Tags: discussion, flagging

*Short introduction:*

I wanted to flag [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176714/c-shortest-path-to-transform-one-word-into-another-rejected-job-application-r) but was alerted that I have 1 declined flag, and should flag with more care. After reviewing what flag was declined, I noticed the similarities.

The flag for this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176621/message-save-and-search-rest-server) was declined, after I flagged it as off-topic because it didn't contain any code. As you can see in the edit history, first it linked to a Github repository which is why I flagged it. Afterwards it was edited to fit the site rules.

Now I got scared to flag [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176714/c-shortest-path-to-transform-one-word-into-another-rejected-job-application-r), because it might be declined again if it is edited.

I guess having many declined flags will induce penalties, that is why I'm a bit wary.

- Should I just not care and flag anyway?
- Did I flag correctly in the first place?

Comment: What message did you get with the decline ?

Comment: None at all, it just states that it has been declined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should double check the reason you flag questions to be closed:

> **should be closed...**
>
> This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about code review request as described in the help center, and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing.

Both flags should be completely invalid, *even if the questions didn't get edited*. Because they're not "unlikely to be fixed via editing."

When I saw the Python post 15 minutes after it being up (around the time I edited the question), I asked the OP to add code to the question, as it'd otherwise be off-topic. Within fifteen minutes of that comment they added their code. A quick and easy edit was all that was needed to make it on-topic.

And so yes you flagged incorrectly.

---

To note, I normally give users an hour or two after commenting to add code to a question before I vote to close it. As otherwise it's a waste of users time in most cases. (Review queue for both close and possibly re-open.)

Comment: I suspected something like this. But atleast now I know what not to do now.

Comment: Just to be clear: this only goes for flagging. The moment you get 'vote to close' privileges, it's a whole different ball game.

Comment: @Mast Luckily I've plenty of time to learn CR guidelines, before that happens.

Comment: @Mast Is it not clear that above the `---` I'm only talking about flagging?

Comment: @Peilonrayz For me and you, sure. But think about the people coming here in a year or so, who may not be as up-to-date with how SE works as we.

Comment: @Peilonrayz As someone that doesn't have VtC privilege on any site (almost on SO) it was only fairly recently that I discovered that vote to close and flagging aren't the same thing, while it's clear above that you're talking about flagging, it's not clear that flagging is so different from VtC

Answer (score 7):

A few occasional mistaken (or disputed) flags are no big deal.  As long as you are flagging posts in good faith, the moderators and the community will appreciate your contribution.  You currently have 52 helpful flags to your credit.

In the worst case, if moderators see that you have a pattern of unjustified flags, we'll send you a message telling you to please stop.  To date, we have never had a need to do that.

Please keep doing what you are doing, and don't be turned off by an automated warning.  Thank you for doing your part to raise the quality of Code Review!